# Colorizing low poly models?

Tags: uv, color, unity, unreal-engine

Is it a must since I am going to use a color palette for basically all the models? I was thinking UV Project or Lightmap Pack methods should set a basic unwrap and then select the faces I want, scale them down a bit (the islands) and place them in the color I want. What is wrong with this process? I found it the fastest though, I imported my model in Unity and looked normal, the shadows, colors, everything, however in Unreal I was given an ''UVs are overlapping by X amount'' error and that made me rethink the way I am doing stuff..
Also I searched how people do it, mostly on youtube, and when they use a color palette they do this too, they do not unwrap them the traditional way so I am honestly really confused.

Comment: Why did you confuse by this error? It is just a warning message. It is just a notification that you use same spot on texture twice.

Comment: One clever method is actually is in creation of small image with color palette, and then just put UV faces in corresponding color spots overlapping them hundreds of times. Then, if you want to change colors (for ex level changed) - just replace this small image - and you have all object colors changed.

Comment: @Crantisz It was confusing why in Unity my model looked good and in Unreal the opposite, making me think if what I did was just a 'cheat' and not the right way, but I am making my game in Unity so should this bother me? or do I keep using this method